# LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Error::ErrorHandler

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to build the error module for the entire application. I've created one error_handler.rb inside lib/error directory and added

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

in config/application.rb.

error_handler.rb

```
module Error
 module ErrorHandler

 def self.included(klass)
  klass.class_eval do
    rescue_from ::ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
      respond(:record_not_found, 404, e.to_s)
    end
    rescue_from ::StandardError do |e|
      respond(:standard_error, 500, e.to_s)
    end
  end
 end

 private
 def respond(_error, _status, _message)
  json = Helpers::Render.json(_error, _status, _message)
  render json: json
 end
end
end
```

I've included this module in ApplicationController

```
include Error::ErrorHandler
```

But whenever I try to hit any errors console is throwing

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Error::ErrorHandler, expected /Users/username/path/lib/error/error_handler.rb to define it):

Error during failsafe response: Unable to autoload constant Error::ErrorHandler
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: You need to add it to `config.autoload_paths` too.

Comment: @fylooi I've tried adding config.autoload_paths also. But the result is the same.

Comment: Also, `error_handler.rb` needs to be in `/lib/error/`

Comment: @fylooi I've mentioned that error_handler.rb is inside lib/error/ directory

Comment: adding `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib"]` and server restart always works for me. I dont know why you facing error. Did you restart server after change in application.rb??

Comment: @SujoyD Yes, I've restarted the server also. When I run 
`bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` it shows lib directory as loaded. But still, it throws the error.

Comment: Does `Error::ErrorHandler` resolve in the console?

Comment: @fylooi Sorry, I didn't get. You mean to run the ErrorHandler in console?

Comment: Just enter `Error::ErrorHandler` in the console and see whether Rails can autoload it

Comment: @fylooi Yes it is loading in console.

Comment: Funny. Sounds like autoload is working just fine if the constant can be resolved in development. In this case, i'd open up Rails' source using `bundle open rails` and toss a few `pry` debug statements around https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04093884a1527777795ad1f17ef1c556e7db9429/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L550, and see how it behaves in the console vs dev server

Comment: Also, Rails' convention would be to extend `ActiveSupport::Concern` in the module, then you can call `rescue_from` in an `included do` block instead of using `class_eval`